# Using Vue test-utils and jest to test the value of a specific input element

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, tdd, vue-test-utils

Using Vue test-utils, I'm needing to test the value of a specific input element which is populated via a prop. I've figured out how to find the element using it's id:

```
  it("Address should render Street 1", () => {
     const street1 = wrapper.find('#street1')              // this works
     expect(street1).toEqual('223 Some Street Rd')         // nope
     expect(street1.text()).toEqual('223 Some Street Rd')  // seemed good at the time
     expect(street1.value()).toEqual('223 Some Street Rd') // grasping at straws - no love 
  });
```

but I've not been able to figure out how to access the "value" of the input.

Any help is appreciated in advance

Answer (score 8):

I am assuming your component looks something like this:

```
 <input id="street1" type="text" v-model="street1" >
```

then you can try

```
   expect(street1.element.value).toEqual('223 Some Street Rd');
```

E.g.

```
import { mount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import Input from "./Input";

describe("Input", () => {
  const mountInput = (propsData = {}) => {
    return mount(Input, {
      propsData
    });
  };

  it("Address should render Street 1", () => {
    const wrapper = mountInput();
    const street1 = wrapper.find('#street1') 
    expect(street1.element.value).toEqual('223 Some Street Rd');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the vue-test-utils [documentation](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/#setprops), you can add props to a component using `propsData` or setProps

```js
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Foo from './Foo.vue'

const wrapper = mount(Foo, {
  propsData: {
    myProp: '223 Some Street Rd' // I am assuming the prop's value is '223 Some Street Rd'
  }
})
const street1 = wrapper.find('#street1') 
expect(street1.text()).toBe('223 Some Street Rd'); //.toEqual should also work
```

Or Alternatively

```js
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import Foo from './Foo.vue';

const wrapper = mount(Foo);
wrapper.setProps({ myProp: '223 Some Street Rd' }) // I am assuming the prop's value is '223 Some Street Rd'
const street1 = wrapper.find('#street1') 
expect(street1.text()).toBe('223 Some Street Rd'); //.toEqual should also work
```